# AWS CLI DynamoDB path with :

Tags: aws-cli

If I scan this way, works fine:

```
 aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --select "COUNT" --filter-expression "attribute_type(destination.amount, :v_sub)" --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json
```

Where `destination.amount` is the correct path:

[image]

But now I want to read from a path like this:

[image]

How can I read from `sender.custom:codigoCorporativa`? I can't do this:

```
 aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --select "COUNT" --filter-expression "attribute_type(sender.custom:codigoCorporativa, :v_sub)" --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json
```

or I'll get this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: ":codigoCorporativa", near: "custom:codigoCorporativa,"
```

I tried to use:

```
sender.custom:codigoCorporativa
"sender.custom:codigoCorporativa"
\"sender.custom:codigoCorporativa\"
sender.'custom:codigoCorporativa'
```

Any idea?

Edit: I've just read in the [AWS DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) that special characters like `#` and `:` should be avoided, but I need to scan now a name with `:`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to use a placeholder:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --select "COUNT" --filter-expression 
"attribute_type(#code, :v_sub)" --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json --expression- 
attribute-names '{"#code":"sender.custom:codigoCorporativa"}'
```